# Shrink MakeHuman model

Tags: modeling, makehuman

I have two MakeHuman models in the same blend. I'm trying to make the second MakeHuman model small but I can't. 
I made the first MakeHuman model small. I did it with the "Scale" command. I didn't have any problem. [image]

I try to do the same with the second MakeHuman model but it doesn't work.
[image]

I use the keys but nothing seems to have happened.
[image]

On the same screen  I have another object, the shoes.
What possible issue could stop a model from scaling when the option is applied to it?

Comment: One thing I can think of is if you linked the second model. It doens't look that way. Anyway, it is a guessing game and you should probably attach your blend file for us to look at.

Comment: @Gunslinger thanks for your comment but I don't understand it.

Comment: Also, make sure to scale the parent armature, not the human mesh. I might be misinterpreting what I'm seeing and that floating armature seen at the back really belongs to a third character that is hidden behind that plane but it looks to me like the armature has a different scale ans transformations than the mesh it's supposed to control....